# Angular2 ng-book-2 simple sample chapter 1 app , it works fine in the browser , but why do I get this error?

Tags: angular2-template

On Mac OS X El Capitan, I follow all the steps from Page 1 to page 18 of this simple app, but at the screen where I run "ng serve" I get this error:

> ERROR in [default]
>   /Users/bob/angular2_hello_world/src/app/user-item/user-item.component.ts:11:8
>   Property 'name' does not exist on type 'UserItemComponent'.

From Page 1 :

Writing your First Angular 2 Web Application
Simple Reddit Clone

TO

Page 18:

Try it out
"After making these changes reload the page and the page should display Hello Felipe""

Answer (score 0):

The error is that you use a "name" variable inside the component template but it's not defined inside the component. Define and use it like this in your component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-item-component',
  template: `
   <h1>{{name}}</h1>
  `,
  styles: []
})
export class AppComponent {

name: string = "Hello Felipe"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, just reading ng-book2-r49, you need to define that name property in class as **names: string[];** so it looks like this

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-item',
  templateUrl: './user-item.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-item.component.css']
})
export class UserItemComponent implements OnInit {
  name: string;

  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Felipe'; // set the name
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```